# fix python pip "The system cannot execute the specified program." in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, pip

can anyone help me in fixing this error when running pip. I have tried every possible answer on the web.

I am using Windows 10 and an i7-64 bit machine.

Please refer to the attached image. If you need more information about this  error reply to it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BStSa.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Have you installed pip? If yes, how did you install pip?

Answer (score 0):

At first, please try next command:
`python -m pip install -U pip`

Answer (score 0):

You should not run it on the directory where `pip` itself is installed,Just open cmd and dont get into any directory ,then type pip!!

Answer (score 0):

Try py instead of using python keyword